# Count of rows where some field is null plus where is not null differs count of total

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table where i have a nullable blob field type (SQL SERVER 2005) used to store images. 
So i have the following situation:

`select count (*) from table where image_field  is null` returns 180000 rows with images.

`select count (*) from table where image_field  is not null` returns 3600000 rows without images.

if i use `select count (*) from table` i don't have 3780000 rows (3600000 + 180000), but a little less.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Did you use `WITH (NOLOCK)` on any of these queries? What does `sys.partitions` say (for total row count)?

Comment: Aaron, thank you. The `sys.partitions` say the same total than using count.

Answer (score 0):

Someone added or deleted a few rows?

Try

```
  Select Count(*) total,
     Sum(case when When image_field is null Then 1 Else 0 End) nullCount,
     Sum(case when When image_field is not null Then 1 Else 0 End) notNulCount
  From table
```

and compare these nums to the ones from individual queries

Comment: Charles thank you for your answer. The results are right doing your suggestion. Do you know why this happens? (to have this difference in the values using count and using sum)

Comment: The difference is not because of `COUNT` vs. `SUM`. The difference is that the same page is read only *once* in this query, whereas in your original queries the pages are read multiple times, and could have changed in the meantime.

Comment: Don't understood. The table isn't changing, nobody is using it right now. Can you explain it another way? :D